# Removing empty line when reading docx file in php

Tags: php, arrays, docx

Before starting.. Im very new to PHP... hope you can bear with me on this.

I've a file (of type .docx) of sentences which i'm splitting where there is a period.

The code i used is:

```
$docObj = new Filetotext($fileToTest);
$docextracted = $docObj->extractText();

 // pattern to find the fullstop
 $pattern = '/\./';
 //giving a new line to each sentence
 $current1= preg_replace($pattern, "\r\n", $docextracted);

 $splitArray = explode("\n", $current1);
 //$mainFile = $splitArray;
 $mainFile = (str_replace(' ', '', $splitArray));
 print_r($mainFile);
```

The file actually contains the following: (for sample purpose only)

```
This is a test file. The purpose of this test file is to ensure that the file reading part is working. This test is important. This test ends here.
```

However when `print_r($mainFile);` gives out the following:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Thisisatestfile
    [2] => Thepurposeofthistestfileistoensurethatthefilereadingpartisworking
    [3] => Thistestisimportant
    [4] => Thistestendshere
    [5] =>
)
```

The empty parts (forgot the word for it) in the first and last array indexes are the issue. I tried other files and same thing. First and last index is empty. This causes an issue when im trying to put a counter on this, or when im trying to compare the array with other arrays.

Is there anything wrong with my code that is bringing the empty part?

Any sort of help is much appreciated :)

Comment: The str_replace suggests instead of blanks, there was whitespace in the first (0th) and the 5th index? Could you try exploding by \r\n rather than just \n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doing a trim on the $current1 to remove the whitespaces before and after, before explode(), should do the trick.

```
....
$current1 = trim($current1);
$splitArray = explode("\n", $current1);
....
```

Comment: This worked!
Also tried array_filter($mainFile) suggested by another user (who has now deleted the answer.) It worked halfway. Removed last index. But This works for both! :) thanks